# How to list storage blob url using az cli?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, az

I want to list (programmatically) the url of my blob storage. The url I am looking for is `https://my_storageaccount_name.blob.core.windows.net/my_container_name/my_file_name`

I tried `az storage account list` and `az storage blob show` but neither of them display the url.

There is a `az storage blob url` but that creates a url. I am interested in listing the url.

Does anyone know how to obtain this ?

Comment: So you want to find the blob of a file given a certain storage account?

Comment: @Paolo that is correct. I want to obtain the url via az cli.

Comment: Is Powershell okay?

Comment: I prefer az cli but will accept Powershell if it provides the information and I dont receive any other answer.

Comment: Thinking about it, why does the solution below not work for you?

Answer (score 3):

If the url for the blobs is always

```
https://my_storageaccount_name.blob.core.windows.net/my_container_name/my_file_name
```

without any custom domains configured, just list all containers with blobs, take the container name and blob name, and put it in the URL.

Ref: https://my_storageaccount_name.blob.core.windows.net/my_container_name/my_file_name

Comment: This does not return the full URL property value for the Blob, which would include the VersionId.

Answer (score 0):

You can get Storage account URL Using

```
az storage account show --name $storage_account_name --resource-group $ResourceGroup --query "primaryEndpoints.blob")
```

or all the properties without using query from which you can pick whichever property you want

```
az storage account show --name $storage_account_name --resource-group $ResourceGroup
```